# Running code after Spring Boot starts

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to run code after my **spring-boot** app starts to monitor a directory for changes.

I have tried running a new thread but the `@Autowired` services have not been set at that point.

I have been able to find `ApplicationPreparedEvent`, which fires before the `@Autowired` annotations are set.  Ideally I would like the event to fire once the application is ready to process http requests.

Is there a better event to use, or a better way of running code after the application is live in **spring-boot**?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/running-setup-logic-on-startup-in-spring

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Try:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        context.getBean(Table.class).fillWithTestdata(); // <-- here
    }
}
```

Comment: this does not work when you deploy application as war file to an external tomcat. It works only with embedded tomcat

Comment: No, it doesn't work. But in this use case I like more explicit way instead of `@Component`. See answer from @cjstehno to get it work in a war file.

Answer (score 705):

It is as simple as this:

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void doSomethingAfterStartup() {
    System.out.println("hello world, I have just started up");
}
```

Tested on version `1.5.1.RELEASE`

Comment: thanks you. this made my code work without any change required. Thanks again for such a simple answer.
This will also work with @RequestMapping annotation without any problem.

Comment: Someone may also wish to use `@EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)` instead, which gets triggered after bean creation, but before the server starts. It can be used to perform activities before any requests hit the server.

Comment: Just to clarify what do you mean by "refresh"? In what cases would that event be triggered?
PS: new to spring boot

Comment: Why is the line "Started application" being printed after the code is executed in the doSomethingAfterStartup() method?

Comment: does this class where you put event listener needs to be annotated with Component, Service etc. ?

Comment: tested on Spring boot 2.0.5.RELEASE

Comment: Tested on 2.2.2 Release. it works perfectly. this solution saves my time.

Comment: Just note that if you use Spring Shell this event will never happen ,because the Spring Shell enter in infinite cycle before the ApplicationReadyEvent.

Comment: Tested on Spring boot 2.4.3. Works perfectly.

Comment: I've tried several other methods in the past. Now i'm working on a different project, and i can tell that this one works particularly BETTER. Thank you !

Comment: tested on spring boot 2.1.0.RELEASE , works fine

Comment: I had to add it into my Application class in order for it to work.

Comment: it should used in class with @Component or a class with Component Type to work correctly

Comment: You can have a bean in your SpringBootApplication like:  `@Bean ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> appReady(InsuranceRepository repository){ return event -> repository.save() }`

Comment: how would you ensure that this code gets execute exactly once only on app start?

Answer (score 153):

Have you tried ApplicationReadyEvent?

```
@Component
public class ApplicationStartup 
implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

  /**
   * This event is executed as late as conceivably possible to indicate that 
   * the application is ready to service requests.
   */
  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(final ApplicationReadyEvent event) {

    // here your code ...

    return;
  }
}
```

Code from: http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/11/13/run-code-at-spring-boot-startup/

This is what the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-spring-application.html#boot-features-application-events-and-listeners) mentions about the startup events:

> ...
>
> Application events are sent in the following order, as your application runs:
>
> An ApplicationStartedEvent is sent at the start of a run, but before
> any processing except the registration of listeners and initializers.
>
> An ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent is sent when the Environment to be used in the context is known, but before the context
> is created.
>
> An ApplicationPreparedEvent is sent just before the refresh is started, but after bean definitions have been loaded.
>
> An ApplicationReadyEvent is sent after the refresh and any related callbacks have been processed to indicate the application is ready to
> service requests.
>
> An ApplicationFailedEvent is sent if there is an exception on startup.
>
> ...

Comment: As an alternative, you can do this using ```@EventListener```annotation on a Bean method, passing as argument the class event you want to hook to.

Comment: This has changed in spring-boot 2. If you are porting up from 1.x and were using ApplicationStartedEvent then you now want ApplicationStartingEvent instead.

Answer (score 102):

Why not just create a bean that starts your monitor on initialization, something like:

```
@Component
public class Monitor {
    @Autowired private SomeService service

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        // start your monitoring in here
    }
}
```

the `init` method will not be called until any autowiring is done for the bean.

Comment: Sometimes `@PostConstruct` fires too early. For example, when using Spring Cloud Stream Kafka, `@PostConstruct` fires before application binds to Kafka. Dave Syer's solution is better because it fires timely.

Comment: `@PostConstruct` happens during the initialisation, not after. Although this can be useful in some cases, it's not the correct answer if you want to run **after** Spring Boot starts. For example, while `@PostConstruct` doesn't finish, none of the endpoints are available.

Comment: Not quite per the OP question. at @PostConstruct, this bean is constructed, like beans in this class scope is autowired, etc. but the application as a whole may not be ready, for instance, other beans may still in the process of injection or wiring.

Comment: If you do anything long-running in the `@PostConstruct` (such as HTTP requests with retry backoffs), you won't get great behavior because sending SIGTERM doesn't interrupt the thread running the `@PostConstruct`, so your app refuses to shutdown until that method exits.

Comment: In multithreading world, there is a chance that ```@PostConstruct``` may cause thread blocking, If your task is running for a long hours.

Answer (score 75):

The "Spring Boot" way is to use a `CommandLineRunner`. Just add beans of that type and you are good to go. In Spring 4.1 (Boot 1.2) there is also a `SmartInitializingBean` which gets a callback after everything has initialized. And there is `SmartLifecycle` (from Spring 3).

Comment: Any example of that? Is it possible to execute a bean after app is running, via command line in an arbitrary moment?

Comment: Don't know what you mean by "arbitrary moment". The Spring Boot user guide and samples have examples of using a `CommandLineRunner` (and the newer `ApplicationRunner`): http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-command-line-runner.

Comment: I found, that Lifecycle is the prefered option to perform asynchronous tasks on start/stop stages of the application, and I'm trying to spot other differences between the CommandLineRunner and the InitializingBeans, but can't find anything about that.

Comment: couple usual [example code](https://gist.github.com/simonovAlexey/51166e11fe80c84f20c19527dd722788) of using `CommandLineRunner`

Comment: Why is it better than `@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)`, if you don't need access to command line arguments?

Answer (score 53):

`ApplicationReadyEvent` is really only useful if the task you want to perform is not a requirement for correct server operation. Starting an async task to monitor something for changes is a good example.

If, however your server is in a 'not ready' state until the task is completed then it's better to implement `SmartInitializingSingleton` because you'll get the callback *before* your REST port has been opened and your server is open for business.

Don't be tempted to use `@PostConstruct` for tasks that should only happen once ever. You'll get a rude surprise when you notice it being called multiple times...

Comment: This should be the chosen answer. As @Andy points out, SmartInitializingSingleton is called just before the ports are opened.

Answer (score 44):

You can extend a class using [`ApplicationRunner`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/ApplicationRunner.html) , override the `run()` method and add the code there.

```
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;

@Component
public class ServerInitializer implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments applicationArguments) throws Exception {

        //code goes here

    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect in Spring Boot. But run() method was called twice when having ApplicationScope for the class. So PostConstruct method with the above worked better.

Answer (score 15):

Use a `SmartInitializingSingleton` bean in spring > 4.1

```
@Bean
public SmartInitializingSingleton importProcessor() {
    return () -> {
        doStuff();
    };

}
```

As alternative a `CommandLineRunner` bean can be implemented or annotating a bean method with `@PostConstruct`.

Comment: Can I require an Autowired dependency inside that method? I'd like to set Profiles

Answer (score 15):

Best way to execute block of code after Spring Boot application started is using PostConstruct annotation.Or also you can use command line runner for the same.

**1. Using PostConstruct annotation**

```
@Configuration
public class InitialDataConfiguration {

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct() {
        System.out.println("Started after Spring boot application !");
    }

}
```

**2. Using command line runner bean**

```
@Configuration
public class InitialDataConfiguration {

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner runner() {
        return args -> {
            System.out.println("CommandLineRunner running in the UnsplashApplication class...");
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe the `@PostConstruct` method is part of the bean initialization. I've seen the ApplicationContext failing to load because of unsatisfied dependency due to failing `@PostConstruct` method.

Comment: Note that both the `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy` annotations are part of Java EE. Since Java EE was deprecated in Java 9, and removed in Java 11, we have to add the dependency manually ( javax.annotation-api)  to use these annotations.

Answer (score 14):

Providing an example for Dave Syer answer, which worked like a charm:

```
@Component
public class CommandLineAppStartupRunner implements CommandLineRunner {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CommandLineAppStartupRunner.class);

    @Override
    public void run(String...args) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Application started with command-line arguments: {} . \n To kill this application, press Ctrl + C.", Arrays.toString(args));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I really like the suggestion for usage of the `EventListener` annotation by @cahen (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44923402/9122660) since it is very clean. Unfortunately I could not get this to work in a Spring + Kotlin setup. What does work for Kotlin is adding the class as a method parameter:

```
@EventListener 
fun doSomethingAfterStartup(event: ApplicationReadyEvent) {
    System.out.println("hello world, I have just started up");
}
```

Comment: Put it in the spring boot application class
not randomly out side
`@SpringBootApplication
class MyApplication {
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent::class)
    fun doSomethingAfterStartup() {
        println("hello world, I have just started up")
    }
}`

Comment: you don't need to put it necessary to the @SpringBootApplication class. any configuration class will do

Answer (score 9):

You have several choices:

**Using `CommandLineRunner` or `ApplicationRunner` as a Bean definition:**

Spring Boot executes these towards the end of the application startup process. In most circumstances, the `CommandLineRunner` will do the job. Following is an example of a CommandLineRunner implementation with Java 8:

```
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner() {
   return (args) -> System.out.println("Hello World");
}
```

Note that the `args` is the String array of arguments. You can also provide an implementation of this interface and define it as a Spring Component:

```
@Component
public class MyCommandLineRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

You can use the `ApplicationRunner` if you need better argument management. ApplicationRunner takes an `ApplicationArguments` instance that has enhanced argument management options.

You can also order the  `CommandLineRunner` and `ApplicationRunner` beans using Spring's `@Order` annotation:

```
 @Bean
 @Order(1)
 public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner() {
    return (args) -> System.out.println("Hello World, Order 1");
 }

 @Bean
 @Order(2)
 public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner() {
    return (args) -> System.out.println("Hello World, Order 2");
 }
```

**Using Spring Boot's ContextRefreshedEvent:**

Spring Boot publishes several events at startup. These events indicate the completion of a phase in the application startup process. You can listen to the `ContextRefreshedEvent` and execute custom code:

```
@EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
public void execute() {
    if(alreadyDone) {
      return;
    }
    System.out.println("hello world");
}
```

`ContextRefreshedEvent` is published several times. Thus, ensure to put a check whether the code execution is already finished.

Answer (score 8):

Try this one and it will run your code when the application context has fully started.

```
 @Component
public class OnStartServer implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent arg0) {
                // EXECUTE YOUR CODE HERE 
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `ContextRefreshedEvent` [_can be triggered multiple times_](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#context-functionality-events)

Answer (score 7):

Spring boot provides an ApplicationRunner interface with a run() method to be invoked at application startup.
However, instead of raw String arguments passed to the callback method, we have an instance of the ApplicationArguments class.

```
@Component
public class AppStartupRunner implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        //some logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/40394259/2047962

Answer (score 4):

just implement CommandLineRunner for spring boot application.
You need to implement run method,

```
public classs SpringBootApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

    @Override
        public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        // write your logic here 

        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use @Component

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
@Slf4j
public class BeerLoader implements CommandLineRunner {
    //declare 

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        //some code here 

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you mean running peace of code once after the application started, you can use the CommandLineRunner as below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootApplication 
  implements CommandLineRunner {

private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
  .getLogger(SpringBootConsoleApplication.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LOG.info("STARTING THE APPLICATION");
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootConsoleApplication.class, args);
    LOG.info("APPLICATION FINISHED");
}

@Override
public void run(String... args) {
    // enter code you want to run after app loaded here
    LOG.info("EXECUTING : command line runner");

    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {
        LOG.info("args[{}]: {}", i, args[i]);
    }
}
```

}

Otherwise, you can use the DevTools dependency, which help you to run new codes without manually restarting the application.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

don't forget to add these codes to your pom.xml to avoid version warnings:

```
   <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

 <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

give it a thump up if this was helpful to you!

Answer (score 1):

I found Andy Brown's answer useful, indicating that `SmartInitializingSingleton` was better for doing some non-asynchronous task that is required before a successful start.

To give a concrete example, the great book [*Cloud Native Spring in Action*](https://www.manning.com/books/cloud-native-spring-in-action) (Manning, 2022) by Thomas Vitale gives the following example on page 122 for loading test data based upon a `testdata` profile by listening for `ApplicationReadyEvent`:

```java
@Component
@Profile("testdata")
public class BookDataLoader {
  private final BookRepository bookRepository;

  public BookDataLoader(BookRepository bookRepository) {
    this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
  }

  @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
  public void loadBookTestData() {
    var book1 = new Book("1234567891", "Northern Lights",
        "Lyra Silverstar", 9.90);
    var book2 = new Book("1234567892", "Polar Journey",
        "Iorek Polarson", 12.90);
    bookRepository.save(book1);
    bookRepository.save(book2);
  }
}
```

Taking Andy Brown's advice, the same functionality could be implemented using `SmartInitializingSingleton` like this:

```java
@Component
@Profile("testdata")
public class BookDataLoader implements SmartInitializingSingleton {
  private final BookRepository bookRepository;

  public BookDataLoader(BookRepository bookRepository) {
    this.bookRepository = bookRepository;
  }

  @Override
  public void afterSingletonsInstantiated() {
    var book1 = new Book("1234567891", "Northern Lights",
        "Lyra Silverstar", 9.90);
    var book2 = new Book("1234567892", "Polar Journey",
        "Iorek Polarson", 12.90);
    bookRepository.save(book1);
    bookRepository.save(book2);
  }
}
```

Note that the only differences are 1) implementing `SmartInitializingSingleton` and 2) overriding `afterSingletonsInstantiated()` instead of annotating an arbitrary method with `@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)`.

This approach is working in my application, and the semantics of `SmartInitializingSingleton` do seem to be a better fit for data initialization, based upon the Spring documentation and comments in the other answers here.

Answer (score 0):

Best way you use CommandLineRunner or ApplicationRunner
The only difference between is run() method
CommandLineRunner accepts array of string and ApplicationRunner accepts  ApplicationArugument.