# Getting "FirebaseApp name AnyAppName already exists" when creating user without signing in

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want Admins to create users. But this will be on the client side as there will be many admins and I don't want that many people to have access to my firebase console. That's why I don't want to use Firebase-Admin SDK.

I have searched many places and found this. Below is that code:

So you can create two different FirebaseAuth objects like:

`private FirebaseAuth mAuth1;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth2;`

Now in the onCreate you can initialize them as:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        mAuth1 = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        FirebaseOptions firebaseOptions = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setDatabaseUrl("[Database_url_here]")
                .setApiKey("Web_API_KEY_HERE")
                .setApplicationId("PROJECT_ID_HERE").build();

        FirebaseApp myApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext(),firebaseOptions,
                "AnyAppName");

        mAuth2 = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(myApp);
//..... other code here
}
```

To get ProjectID, WebAPI key you can go to Project Settings in your firebase project console.

Now to create the user account you have to use `mAuth2`, not `mAuth1`. And then on successful registration, you can log out that `mAuth2` user.

Example:

```
private void createAccount(String email, String password)
    {
        mAuth2.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {


                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            String ex = task.getException().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration Failed"+ex,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration successful",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            mAuth2.signOut();
                        }



                        // ...
                    }
                });

    }
```

But here I am able to create users but only once. After that I am not able to reopen that activity again. It is showing "FirebaseApp name AnyAppName already exists!".

Comment: I think you should rephrase your question. Your current question would be answered with [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37517208/firebase-kicks-out-current-user/38013551#38013551). But in you last line you say you can actually do that but you have a different problem.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: [FirebaseApp name DEFAULT already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787330/java-ee-firebaseapp-name-default-already-exists)

Comment: Yes I saw your answer way before. But I wanted it in Java. In your answer also see Jimmy's comment. He had to add  `secondaryApp.delete();`. But in Java what is the workaround?

Comment: I dont think you have to delete it if i look at the other question i linked. Can you try to check to see if the app exists before you initialize it again in your oncreate? (something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47387163/4916627))

Comment: I am able to create as many users as I want until I stay in that activity. But as soon as go back and enter again the app crashes. Error in Log: `FirebaseApp name AnyAppName already exists!`. Thats why the `FirebaseApp` object `myApp` which was created is still there. I don't know if that makes any sense or not. I am new to Firebase.

Comment: And that is exactly why you should check if it exists before you try to create it (again). If you don't know how you could check out [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634767/how-to-connect-to-more-than-one-firebase-database-from-an-android-app/37643374?noredirect=1#comment62899818_37643374) or maybe [this blog](https://sdgsystems.com/blog/firebase-connection-management)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of initializing simply. Do this:

```
 try { FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext(), firebaseOptions, "AnyAppName");
            mAuth2 = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(app);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e){
            mAuth2 = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(FirebaseApp.getInstance("AnyAppName"));
        }
```