# Import JSON file in Mongo db using Spring Data Embedded Mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I am trying to write some integration tests relative to some methods that needs to extract data from MongoDB. In detail, I am using the [Embedded Mongo](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-nosql.html#boot-features-mongo-embedded) given by Spring Data project. The embedded mongo is clearly provided by [Flapdoodle](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo).

I need to import some json file into the Embedded Mongo. I have looked at the tests provided with *flapdoodle*, but I am not able to understand how they integrates with the *magic* given by Spring Data + Spring Boot.

Can anyone post some clarifying snippets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a junit rule ([ExternalResource](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/rules/ExternalResource.java)) which runs before and after each test. Check the `MongoEmbeddedRule` class to get some idea on the implementation details.

**Integration test:**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
public abstract class TestRunner {

    @Autowired
    protected MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Rule
    public MongoEmbeddedRule mongoEmbeddedRule = new MongoEmbeddedRule(this);
```

**ExternalResource Rule:**

```
public class MongoEmbeddedRule extends ExternalResource {

    private final Object testClassInstance;
    private final Map<String, Path> mongoCollectionDataPaths;
    private final String fieldName;
    private final String getterName;

    public MongoEmbeddedRule(final Object testClassInstance) {
        this(testClassInstance, "mongoTemplate", "getMongoTemplate");
    }

    protected MongoEmbeddedRule(final Object testClassInstance, final String fieldName, final String getterName) {
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
        this.getterName = getterName;
        this.testClassInstance = testClassInstance;
        this.mongoCollectionDataPaths = mongoExtendedJsonFilesLookup();
    }

    @Override
    protected void before() {
        dropCollections();
        createAndPopulateCollections();
    }

    @Override
    protected void after() {
    }

    protected Set<String> getMongoCollectionNames() {
        return mongoCollectionDataPaths.keySet();
    }

    public void dropCollections() {
        getMongoCollectionNames().forEach(collectionName -> getMongoTemplate().dropCollection(collectionName));
    }

    protected void createAndPopulateCollections() {
        mongoCollectionDataPaths.forEach((key, value) -> insertDocumentsFromMongoExtendedJsonFile(value, key));
    }

    protected MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate() {
        try {
            Object value = ReflectionTestUtils.getField(testClassInstance, fieldName);
            if (value instanceof MongoTemplate) {
                return (MongoTemplate) value;
            }
            value = ReflectionTestUtils.invokeGetterMethod(testClassInstance, getterName);
            if (value instanceof MongoTemplate) {
                return (MongoTemplate) value;
            }
        } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // throw exception with dedicated message at the end
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                String.format(
                        "%s expects either field '%s' or method '%s' in order to access the required MongoTemmplate",
                        this.getClass().getSimpleName(), fieldName, getterName));
    }

    private Map<String, Path> mongoExtendedJsonFilesLookup() {
        Map<String, Path> collections = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            Files.walk(Paths.get("src","test","resources","mongo"))
                    .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                    .forEach(filePath -> collections.put(
                            filePath.getFileName().toString().replace(".json", ""),
                            filePath));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return collections;
    }

    private void insertDocumentsFromMongoExtendedJsonFile(Path path, String collectionName) {
        try {
            List<Document> documents = new ArrayList<>();
            Files.readAllLines(path).forEach(l -> documents.add(Document.parse(l)));
            getMongoTemplate().getCollection(collectionName).insertMany(documents);
            System.out.println(documents.size() + " documents loaded for " + collectionName + " collection.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**json file** (names.json) with [MongoDB Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/), where every document is in one line and the collection name is the filename without extension.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("594d324d5b49b78da8ce2f28"), "someId" : NumberLong(1), "name" : "Some Name 1", "lastModified" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z")}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("594d324d5b49b78da8ce2f29"), "someId" : NumberLong(2), "name" : "Some Name 2", "lastModified" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z")}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at this following Test class, provided by "flapdoodle". The test shows how to import a JSON file containing the collection dataset:
[MongoImportExecutableTest.java](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo/blob/master/src/test/java/de/flapdoodle/embed/mongo/MongoImportExecutableTest.java)

You could theoretically also import a whole dump of a database. (using MongoDB restore):
[MongoRestoreExecutableTest.java](https://github.com/flapdoodle-oss/de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo/blob/master/src/test/java/de/flapdoodle/embed/mongo/MongoRestoreExecutableTest.java)

Comment: Thanks. However, I asked an example that also uses Spring Boot :)

Comment: Hi. I think you could run the import of data on or after spring boot has started. See hier an example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405713/running-code-after-spring-boot-starts

Answer (score 0):

You can create an abstract class and have setup logic to start mongod and mongoimport process.

**AbstractMongoDBTest.java**

```
public abstract class AbstractMongoDBTest {

private MongodProcess mongodProcess;
private MongoImportProcess mongoImportProcess;
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

void setup(String dbName, String collection, String jsonFile) throws Exception {
    String ip = "localhost";
    int port = 12345;

    IMongodConfig mongodConfig = new MongodConfigBuilder().version(Version.Main.PRODUCTION)
            .net(new Net(ip, port, Network.localhostIsIPv6()))
            .build();

    MongodStarter starter = MongodStarter.getDefaultInstance();
    MongodExecutable mongodExecutable = starter.prepare(mongodConfig);

    File dataFile = new File(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(jsonFile).getFile());
    MongoImportExecutable mongoImportExecutable = mongoImportExecutable(port, dbName,
            collection, dataFile.getAbsolutePath()
            , true, true, true);

    mongodProcess = mongodExecutable.start();
    mongoImportProcess = mongoImportExecutable.start();

    mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(new MongoClient(ip, port), dbName);
}

private MongoImportExecutable mongoImportExecutable(int port, String dbName, String collection, String jsonFile,
                                                    Boolean jsonArray, Boolean upsert, Boolean drop) throws
        IOException {
    IMongoImportConfig mongoImportConfig = new MongoImportConfigBuilder()
            .version(Version.Main.PRODUCTION)
            .net(new Net(port, Network.localhostIsIPv6()))
            .db(dbName)
            .collection(collection)
            .upsert(upsert)
            .dropCollection(drop)
            .jsonArray(jsonArray)
            .importFile(jsonFile)
            .build();

    return MongoImportStarter.getDefaultInstance().prepare(mongoImportConfig);
}

@AfterEach
void clean() {
    mongoImportProcess.stop();
    mongodProcess.stop();
}

public MongoTemplate getMongoTemplate(){
    return mongoTemplate;
}
```

}

**YourTestClass.java**

```
public class YourTestClass extends AbstractMongoDBTest{


@BeforeEach
void setup() throws Exception {
    super.setup("db", "collection", "jsonfile");
}

@Test
void test() throws Exception {

}
```

}

Comment: I really like your example. But I don't understand how I can autowire (@Autowired) a repository and load the data from the database. Could you add this to your solution?