# Execute method after jHipster application started

Tags: java, jhipster

I want to execute a method after, jHipster application started. Where should I put my method?
I tried to run my method in `MyApp.java` method:

```
    @PostConstruct
    public void initApplication()
```

But I got error:

```
 Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: xxx.xxx.xxx
xxx.xxx.xxx.cars, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

Answer (score 3):

You should define a separate class that you annotate either with `@Service`, `@Component` or `@Configuration` depending on what you want to achieve and inject into this class the JPA repository you need to init your data.

This class could also implement [ApplicationRunner interface](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-command-line-runner).

Alternatively, you may consider loading data from a CSV file using a Liquibase migration, see `src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml` and`users.csv` for an example

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

First option : make your main class implements CommandLineRunner.

```
public class MyJhipsterApp implements CommandLineRunner{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
     //jhipster codes ...
  }

    //method implemented from CommandLineRunner
    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        log.info("hello world, I have just started up");
    }
}
```

Second option : create a configuration file and listen to ApplicationReadyEvent to fire your method.

```
@Configuration
public class ProjectConfiguration {
    private static final Logger log = 
   LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProjectConfiguration.class);

   @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
   public void doSomethingAfterStartup() {
    log.info("hello world, I have just started up");
  }
}
```

Personally, I prefer the second one.

Comment: `@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)` worked for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Jhipster is based on SpringBoot for the backend so the solution might be to add the method in the SpringBoot configuration main, like described in this link : [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405713/running-code-after-spring-boot-starts)

Just in case the solution gets deleted, here is the code :

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        context.getBean(Table.class).fillWithTestdata(); // <-- here
    }
}
```

You can annotate the method you're calling with *@Async* if you don't want it to be blocking.

Hope this helps ! Don't hesitate to ask for more details.

Comment: I try your solution, but still, I get the same error.

Comment: Maybe if you edit your question and add more details I'll be able to help. Has @gaelmarziou answer helped you ?