# where to place suggested code

Tags: java, spring

I am a newbie to Spring. I have a spring project that I want to run some code after it finishes startup. There is a sol'n offered here:

[suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405713/running-code-after-spring-boot-starts)

specifically, I would like to try:

```
 @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class) public void doSomethingAfterStartup() { System.out.println("hello world, I have just started up"); }
```

My question is where in the project to put this code? 
(there are a bunch of code files in various directories)

Comment: Any Spring managed class (bean), e.g. any class annotated with `@Component`, `@Configuration`, `@Controller`, `@Service`, etc.

Comment: Thank you Andreas