# Machine learning with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, machine-learning

I have a spring boot application that contains some machine learning Weight files? I want to know does spring boot Initializes the class on Container Startup? Or does it do this when a certain request Comes in? I don't want to parse those files everytime HTTP request comes in? Is their a way i read those files once and use them on every request?

Comment: you can refer below link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405713/running-code-after-spring-boot-starts?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write custom class like this

```
@Component
public class ApplicationStartup 
implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

  /**
   * This event is executed as late as conceivably possible to indicate that 
   * the application is ready to service requests.
   */
  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(final ApplicationReadyEvent event) {

    // here your code ...

    return;
  }
}
```