# Running code When Spring Boot starts

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

i have a treatment in the method run of the CommandLineRunner interface that creates indexes in elasticsearch, the creation of indexes is done after the application is run. in the console of elasticsearch i can see the the creation's trace. for example:

> [2018-05-29T14:22:38,579][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService]
>   [oYrx3Ep] [country] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards
>   [5]/[1], mappings []
>
> [2018-05-29T14:23:41,296][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexService]
>   [oYrx3Ep] [category] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards
>   [5]/[1], mappings []
>
> ...

how can i execute the method when the app is still in the process of being run, i don't want it to be executed after the app is run

```
  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
       ....
        try {
          Response response = elasticsearchConfiguration.restClient().performRequest("HEAD", "/" + indexName);
          Integer statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
          if (statusCode.equals(STATUS_CODE)) {
            restHighLevelClient.indices().create(new CreateIndexRequest(indexName));
          }
        } catch (IOException e) {
          logger.error(ERROR + e);
        }
       ....
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405713/running-code-after-spring-boot-starts has several ways, in a component  a `@PostConstruct` or `@EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)` annotated method for example. Also http://www.baeldung.com/running-setup-logic-on-startup-in-spring is a nice overview