# Spring Boot: Retrieve config via rest call upon application startup

Tags: spring-boot

I d like to make a REST call once on application startup to retrieve some configuration parameters.

For example, we need to retrieve an entity called FleetConfiguration from another server. I d like to do a GET once and save the keep the data in memory for the rest of the runtime.

**What s the best way of doing this in Spring? using Bean, Config annotations ..?**

I found this for example : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44923402/494659

I might as well use POJOs handle the lifecycle of it myself but I am sure there s a way to do it in Spring without re-inventing the wheel.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following method will run once the application starts, call the remote server and return a FleetConfiguration object which will be available throughout your app. The FleetConfiguration object will be a singleton and won't change.

```
@Bean
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public FleetConfiguration getFleetConfiguration(){
    RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
    String url = "http://remoteserver/fleetConfiguration";
    return rest.getForObject(url, FleetConfiguration.class);
}
```

The method should be declared in a `@Configuration` class or `@Service` class.

Ideally the call should test for the response code from the remote server and act accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Better approach is to use [Spring Cloud Config](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/) to externalize every application's configuration here and it can be updated at runtime for any config change so no downtime either around same.

Comment: thanks! we ll consider it. in the meantime, i need to find an solution to my problem tho :)

Comment: How about a method annotated with `@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)` and `@Bean` that uses a Spring `RestTemplate` to make the call.

Comment: that s what i m going for now.