# Spring Boot: Initially data parsing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am searching for a way to read and parse a lot of data when the spring boot app is starting and be able to use these data later in other classes.

I started with a class `DataRepository.java` and annotated it with `@Service` to be able to inject it later. I'm planning to read the data here and to inject it in any other class I need the data.

But how can I achieve to parse the data just once and at app startup? The spring boot app should only be reachable if the parsing is done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running code after Spring Boot starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405713/running-code-after-spring-boot-starts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach with `@Service` is 100% appropriate.

By default all beans are singletons, so if you parse data on bean creation (in constructor) it will be parsed only once, and this info can be used in other beans by simple injection.

Please note that if during data parsing you have to use **other beans**, you should be confident that all beans are completely constructed. For that you should use approach proposed by [@jreznot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/840129/jreznot):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51783858/5289288

Comment: Ahh ok, I just generated a random value as test data and injected my service in different controllers and the value is always the same so I'm more than convinced. Thank you!

Comment: This is not answer for > But how can I achieve to parse the data just once and at app startup?

Comment: @jreznot since bean is singleton, it's constructor is called only once, so all the code is ran only once. Is that clearer?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ContextStartedEvent` and handle it:

```
@Component
public class ContextStartedListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextStartedEvent> {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextStartedEvent cse) {
        System.out.println("Handling context start event. ");
    }
}
```

See also: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-events

Answer (score 1):

By default all beans in spring context are singletons. Spring guarantees that it will creates a bean just ones during context loading.
For example if you will have few contexts in your application it creates one instance for every context.

If you have just one context you can use these approaches:

- initialize data in constructor. Data will initialized and ready to
  use just after bean's instance creation.

  ```
  @Component
  public class DataRepository {

     public DataRepository() {
         ... init data
     }
  }
  ```
- use `@Bean` annotation with`init` method. Allows you don't stick to Spring in 
  your data repository and initialize data after all beans were created.

  ```
   public class DataRepository {

        public void init() {
              ... init data
        }
   }

  @Configuration
  public class DataRepositoryConfiguration {

       @Bean(initMethod = "init")
       public DataRepository dataRepository() {
          return new DataRepository();
       }
  ```
- use `@Bean` annotation and invoke `init` method. Allows you don't stick to 
  Spring in your data repository, but `@Autowired` field will uninitialized.

  ```
  public class DataRepository {

        public void init() {
              ... init data
        }
   }

  @Configuration
  public class DataRepositoryConfiguration {
       @Bean
       public DataRepository dataRepository() { 
          DataRepository dr = new new DataRepository();
          dr.init();
          return dr;
       }

  }
  ```
- use `@PostConstruct` annotation. Initialize data after all beans was
  created.

  ```
  public class DataRepository {

     @PostConstruct
     public void init() {
        ... init data
     }
  }
  ```

Exception thrown during initializing will stop Spring's context initializing

Comment: You cannot use beans from `@PostConstruct`. There is no guarantee that dependencies of the class are initialized.

Comment: @jreznot Agree, but it fair for `@Autowired` fields, but not for `@Autowire` constructor. Original question was about initializing data just ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can  use `PostConstruct` on any bean.  For example

```
@Component
class DataLoad {

 ......
 ......


  @PostConstruct
  public void parseData() {

    ...... do your stuff here.......
  }
}
```

With this the code inside parseData will be called only once. This is a very common way to do things in scenarios like when you want to load some configuration data from database at the start of the application and do it only once. In these cases you can `@Autowired` the repository class to the same class and use that in your `@PostConstruct` method and get data

Comment: You cannot use beans from `@PostConstruct`. There is no guarantee that dependencies of the class are initialized.

Comment: when you add that as a dependency in the class (using `@Autowired`), spring will intialize that first.

Comment: There is no order of execution defined for beans both having `@PostConstruct`