# @Autowired notation is not working as expected

Tags: spring, spring-boot, autowired

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication {

    @Autowired
    static BibliographyIndexer bi;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
        bi.reindex();
    }

}


@Repository
public class BibliographyIndexer {
    ...
}
```

Whenever I access the properties of `bi` I get a `NullPointerException`. I know the `@Autowired` notation didn't work. But why?

**Note:** both classes are under the same package.

**Additional question**: Since I want to run a method upon the start of the spring application. Is this the best approach since @pepevalbe's answer already gave me the workaround I needed. Is there another way to run a method upon the start of the spring application?

Comment: remove static from BibliographyIndexer

Comment: but then I will not be able to access it under the main function.

Comment: you cannot inject `static` fields. Nor shoul dyou access it like that in your `main`. The `run` method returns an `ApplicationContext` which you can use to obtain a `BibliographyIndexer` using `getBean`. Or create an `@Bean` method which returns a `CommandLineRunner` which you give a `BibliographyIndexer` and invoke the method there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can't @Autorwire an static class. It doesn't get initialized so you get  a NPE when trying to use it.

There are workarounds to wire a bean into a static class, but it is strongly discouraged.

**EDIT:**
If you need to execute code after initilization you could add an event listener:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication {

    @Autowired  
    BibliographyIndexer bi;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void doAfterStartUp() {
        bi.reindex();
    }
}
```

Comment: If that's the case then how will I be able to use any of my autowired variables under the main function without declaring them as static?

Comment: You shouldn't write code under the main function. If you need to execute code after initialization you can add an event listener. I will extend my answer for that

Comment: Under the main function, I instantiated an object that uses the autowired class. But when I use that object and access the autowired class, it is still null.

Comment: Is this the best approach in running a method upon the start of the spring application?

Comment: There are many alternatives, you could write a component class that implements the CommandLineRunner or the ApplicationRunner interfaces. Here you have some examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405713/running-code-after-spring-boot-starts

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons @Autowired might not work.

When a new instance is created not by Spring but by for example manually calling a constructor, the instance of the class will not be registered in the Spring context and thus not available for dependency injection. Also when you use @Autowired in the class of which you created a new instance, the Spring context will not be known to it and thus most likely this will also fail.
Another reason can be that the class you want to use @Autowired in, is not picked up by the ComponentScan. This can basically be because of two reasons.

The package is outside the ComponentScan search path. Move the package to a scanned location or configure the ComponentScan to fix this.
The class in which you want to use @Autowired does not have a Spring annotation. Add one of the following annotatons to the class: @Component, @Repository, @Service, @Controller, @Configuration. They have different behaviors so choose carefully........

Answer (score 0):

In `main` method you can refer to `context` and from it get access to bean `BibliographyIndexer`. In `static main` spring can not creates and injects bean so this is how you can get it from `context`.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ApplicationContext  context = SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
  BibliographyIndexer bibliographyIndexer = context.getBean(BibliographyIndexer.class);
  bibliographyIndexer.reindex();
}
```

You can also do as in [answer  from pepevalbe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58815112/11733759) and execute this code after initialization.

Comment: Is this necessary? I'm seeing examples that doesn't explicitly do this.

Comment: In static main spring can not creates and injects bean so this is how you can get it from context. @olivakyle

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you cannot use `bi` in `main` because `main` is static.
Making `bi` static doesn't help because static fields will not be `@Autowired` (It is possible but does not make sense in the concepts of Dependency Injection).

Remove `static` and move `bi.reindex()` to a new method annotated with `@PostConstruct`. It will be executed after the MainApplication-bean is fully initialized and here you can use your injected `bi`.