# Is there any standard tools to update MongoDB collections with Spring Boot during start-up?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, schema-migration

I use flyway or liquibase to manage my schema and to update some table in application during start-up. I wondering if there is some way to update mongodb collections during start-up? I want to add one new field to collection and provide a value for that field for all old objects

Answer (score 0):

First update your object, create repository then create a function that will update all of the old objects. Then call your function using this reference "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405713/running-code-after-spring-boot-starts".

For the updating and creating of repository you can watch tutorials on youtube.