# Spring boot run cron job only once after Every restart of the App

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cron

i have spring boot project with a cron job. the job should be run only once. it should trigger again only if app is crashed or app is restarted.
is there any cron expression for this ?
or any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Cron is a time based scheduler. It's the wrong tool for jobs that only need to run once.

Comment: you should not use a cron expression for this, just use the logic to run whenever the app starts.

Answer (score 5):

If run once when app start, that is not a *cron* IMHO... Actually you only need to run it when you application finishes booting. Thus, listen to the application booted event, and run your code then. For example, this one: [Running code after Spring Boot starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405713/running-code-after-spring-boot-starts)