# How make spring batch job execute only once

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch, cron-task

I am new to Spring Batch, I have a Spring Boot App, and I want to set up a job that executes only once after Spring Boot app gets started, as we will run app each day

In my current solution, I tried to use attribute `@Scheduled`, but I am not sure what value it should have.

```
    @Scheduled(cron = "0/10 * * * * *")
    public void runMyJob() {
        jobLauncher.run(job, newExecution());
   }

    private JobParameters newExecution() {
        Map<String, JobParameter> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        JobParameter parameter = new JobParameter(new Date());
        parameters.put("currentTime", parameter);
        return new JobParameters(parameters);
    }
}


    @Bean
    public Step jobStep(ItemReader<ReadObject> reader,
                        ItemWriter<WriteObject> writer,
                        StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("jobStep1")
                .<ReadObject, WriteObject>chunk(1)
                .reader(reader)
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job myJob(Step jobStep,
                          JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("myJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(jobStep)
                .end()
                .build();
    }
}


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableScheduling
public class SpringBatchApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            SpringApplication.run(SpringBatchApplication.class, args);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please check this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405713/running-code-after-spring-boot-st)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running code after Spring Boot starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405713/running-code-after-spring-boot-starts)

Comment: @Ali.Wassouf Nope, that question explains how to run something after spring boot start-up, but my question is more focused on Batch job. I am not sure which value @ Scheduled should have, and how I must call the job to start only once

Comment: This is probably because Spring Boot runs your job at startup a first time and then the `@Scheduled` method runs it a second time when the specified time arrives. Is that the case? Have you disabled the first run by Spring boot using `spring.batch.job.enabled=false`?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I have set `spring.batch.job.enabled=false`, but it still executes the jobs every second or even more frequently

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation and the reason why my jobs were executed repeatedly is that I didn't return `null` in the reader. From the documentation of the `ItemReader`'s `read`:

> Reads a piece of input data and advance to the next one. Implementations **must** return `null` at the end of the input data set.

So if you don't return `null` at all, it's going to read the same input forever. I solved it using a flag in the reader:

```
private boolean endOfInput = false;

public ReadObject read() {
    if (endOfInput) {
        endOfInput = false;
        return null;
    }
    endOfInput = true;

    // read your input chunk
    return chunk;
}
```