# Spring Boot ApplicationReadyEvent guarantee that *every* REST service is fully deployed and running?

Tags: spring-boot, events

I need to launch a process after the embedded Tomcat and every REST service are fully operational.

Is **ApplicationReadyEvent** thrown after Tomcat is launched, **and** every single webapp and REST service is fully deployed?  Or is there a better/later event I should use?

---

I scoured the internet and the closest discussion I could find is  [Running Code After Spring Boot Starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405713/running-code-after-spring-boot-starts), although it does not delve into the REST service readiness matter and I could not simply ask for clarification in the best answer (not enough reputation yet).

Simply testing isn't going to help since I plan to add quite a few large REST services over time which will stretch startup times so I could succeed now and fail later.

Comment: Spring Boot Actuator /health endpoint returns `"UP"` if everything is ready. This is what loadbalancers usually use to figure out if a node is ready to serve requests.

Comment: What do you need to launch? And no that event will not fire for multiple applications. Each application (spring boot) will fire this event.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single Spring Boot Application and you can add your code inside it then `ApplicationReadyEvent` is the right one for your requirements.

Comment: Thank, you.   It is indeed a single application with quite a few REST services in it.